# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out ERROR

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Currently receiving error System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

I have tried increasing the executionTimeout property in the configuration editor in IIS and also adding conn.ConnectionTimeout = 200 , conn.commandtimeout= 200 in the code where I get the error Property 'ConnectionTimeout' is 'ReadOnly'.

Compiler Error Message: BC30526: Property 'ConnectionTimeout' is 'ReadOnly'.

Where do I need to put the connection and command timeouts ?

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("server=xxx; database=xxx; user ID = xxx; Connect Timeout=30")
    
        Dim sqlconna As New SqlCommand
        sqlconna.Connection = conn
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        cmdStringinv = "EXEC myquery "

      Dim cmdb As New SqlCommand(cmdStringinv, conn)
    
    
      conn.Open()
    
      adapter.SelectCommand = cmdb

      adapter.Fill(ds, "Part")
      maxrows = ds.Tables("Part").Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be including your database objects in `Using` blocks. You declare `sqlconn`a but never use it. Your code shows no use for a `DataSet` or `DataAdapter`. If all you want is `Count` then use `.ExecuteScalar`. The error you first mention does not sound like a database error. Is this code running asynchronously? Anyway, here is my interpretation of the code your provided.

```
Private Function GetRowCount() As Long
    Dim maxrows As Long
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=xxx; database=xxx; user ID = xxx;"),
            cmdb As New SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From SomeTable;", conn)
        conn.Open()
        maxrows = CLng(cmdb.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    Return maxrows
End Function
```

Comment: The code usually works fine. It’s just where and how to include the timeout.